# is below mysql Query cause huge load on server

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have executed below query

```
select a.* from table1 a, table2 b where a.x!=b.x;
```

As server is hang i am not able to provide exact structure of both tables. Server is having huge load.

table1 has no indexes and table two has index on x.

I have explain output for similar query.

```
select a.* from table1 a, table2 b where a.x!=b.x;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+----------------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref            | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+----------------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL  | NULL    | NULL           | 70503 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | email         | email | 386     | ASP_DB.b.email |     1 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+----------------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please can any one help in regrading this...

table1 has 69264 rows and table2 has 3332349 rows and it is mysql query

Comment: The following query would have duplicates, since you can have a.x > b.x and a.x < b.x, 2 rows will be shown in this case. replace a.x!=b.x with a.x>b.x.

Comment: Not sure I answered your question though regarding the server-hang. perhaps the two tables have tons of data? you need to provide more info about the table structures

Comment: I have dited my question... Please check it once...

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you want to select. So far you say: Give me all records of table1 and for each of these records all non-matching records of table2 (i.e. where the id does not match). This is likely to give you hundreds of millions of rows.

Comment: I have executed in such a manner that i want unmatched records which are in table2..Any how i can get this with left or right join.... and i expect 0 rows as output

Comment: Say your table1 has four records with x = 1, 2, 3 and 4. Your table has 3 records with x = 1, 4 and 5. This gives you 10 result records: 1-4, 1-5, 2-1, 2-4, 2-5, 3-1, 3-4, 3-5, 4-1, 4-5. You are kind of multiplying your records. This is certainly not what you want. So, what *do* you want? All records in table1 that have no correspondence in table2 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* from table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table2 b 
ON a.x=b.x
WHERE b.x IS NULL
```

An index on b.x will help.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX (x);
```

Comment: Please let me know whether above query in my question will use index or not.

Comment: currently i dont have index on table1...so will a.email!=b.email query use index on table to and will i get same explain plan as i shown before for a.email=b.email

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stretch what I THINK you mean, and if I am incorrect, you will need to clarify better in your question.

It sounds like what you are looking for is that for every record in TableA that does not yet exist in TableB based on the common column of "X".  For example, you have a master email address list in table B and trying to import new records via table A, but there might be some records in table A that already exist in B and you don't care about those based on the common email address column.  This is just an example explanation, but may better represent what you asked for.

If this IS the case, then your "B" table has the index on email and the query would be done with a LEFT-JOIN.

```
select 
      a.*
   from
      TableA a
         LEFT JOIN TableB b
            on a.email = b.email
   where
      b.email is null
```

By doing a LEFT-JOIN, you are telling the engine to try and match on the common "email" address column.  if so, great, join the records between the tables together.

Now, the WHERE clause.  Since you want those that ARE NOT already in the tableB, the where clause is saying where b.email is NULL.  This is basically stating.  After the POSSIBLE join, only give me the records that DO NOT have a match in the other table.